# New phtml file and call it from CMS

Tags: magento2, cms, phtml

I am using Luma default theme in Magento 2 and I want to create a new phtml file and call it from CMS.

Can anyone tell me in which path i need to create my file and how to call it form CMS?

I trying to create in this path: `C:\xampp2\htdocs\medipoint\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Special_Price\special_price.phtml`

and call it in this way:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myname" template="Magento_Theme::Special_price/special_price.phtml"}}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: is Magento_Theme your module name ?

Comment: you have  to first create your theme

Comment: i am new in magneto so i don't know. i am using default Luma theme

Comment: Have you create new theme?

Comment: no. actually i want only to create a single page in my current theme and use it in cms. is that possible?

Comment: for those you have to create your custom theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Completely.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myname" template="Magento_Theme::Special_price/special_price.phtml"}}
```

But file must be locate in correct path

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/YourThemePackage/Magento_Theme/templates/Special_price/special_price.phtml
```

If you are using Luma theme then file path :

```
magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/templates/Special_price/special_price.phtml
```